# Accessing individual values from json array in jquery ajax

Tags: jquery, json, codeigniter

I have an array returned by AJAX in jQuery. I wanted to iterate through the AJAX success result and take individual values from the JSON array. The data is returned in the form of a string. I'm using jQuery's `$.ajax` to get it from the server, which works fine.

```
//my View
$.ajax({
    type: "POST",
    url:"http://localhost:8888/CodeIgniter/index.php/user/usercontroller/search",//controller function
    cache: false,
    data:{"responsible1":res1},
    success: function(data21) { 
        alert(data21);
    });
});
```

> ```
> //data 21 alerts the following
> {"taskname":"Coding","projname":"Easy Wedding"} 
> {"taskname":"Maintain","projname":"Easy Wedding"}
> {"taskname":"Flow Chart","projname":"Fnn"}
> {"taskname":"development in ","projname":"Fnn"}
> {"taskname":"flow chart","projname":"Art gallery"}
> ```

How can I access only individual `taskname` and `projectname` or how can I convert `data21` to an array

Comment: That's not a valid JSON object array. Are you sure that's the data that's being returned? It should look like `[{...}, {...}, {...}]`.

Answer (score 5):

just add `dataType: "json"` to your request, and you will get your data as object but this would just work if you put the return data into these brackets: []

otherwise use this

```
data21 = $.parseJSON('[' + data21.replace(/\"}/g, '"},').replace(/,$/, "") + ']');
console.log(data21);
```

[example](http://jsfiddle.net/WyY27/)

Comment: yaa i have added datatype bt its nt wrking and its giving same alerts

Answer (score 1):

```
success: function(data) { 
data = jQuery.parseJSON(data);  
//now you can access the individual keys like alert(data.taskname+ " : "+data.projname)
    alert(data.taskname+ " : "+data.projname);
});
```

Comment: yaa i can access if it alerts only      ...{"taskname":"Coding","projname":"Easy Wedding"}......bt its not working with multiples ...{"taskname":"Coding","projname":"Easy Wedding"} 
{"taskname":"Maintain","projname":"Easy Wedding"}
{"taskname":"Flow Chart","projname":"Fnn"}

Answer (score 0):

As long as the JSON is valid, you should be able to access the object array with indexes.

If this is the data being returned:

```
[
    {"taskname":"Coding","projname":"Easy Wedding"},
    {"taskname":"Maintain","projname":"Easy Wedding"},
    {"taskname":"Flow Chart","projname":"Fnn"},
    {"taskname":"development in ","projname":"Fnn"},
    {"taskname":"flow chart","projname":"Art gallery"}
]
```

Then this will work:

```
$.ajax({
    type: "POST",
    url: "http://localhost:8888/CodeIgniter/index.php/user/usercontroller/search",
    cache: false,
    dataType: "json",
    data: { "responsible1":res1 },
    success: function(data) { 
        alert(data[0].taskname);
    });
});
```

Answer (score 0):

May be this help you.

```
var  t = { 
   'rows': [
        {"taskname":"Coding","projname":"Easy Wedding"},
        {"taskname":"Maintain","projname":"Easy Wedding"},
        {"taskname":"Flow Chart","projname":"Fnn"},
        {"taskname":"development in ","projname":"Fnn"},
        {"taskname":"flow chart","projname":"Art gallery"}
    ]
}



$.each(t.rows,function(index,value){
    for(var i in value){
        alert(i+' -> '+value[i]);
    }
});
```

This is the way to read json data that i think. Where t is containing json data

**EDIT :**

I'm not familiar with codeigniter but if you put below code in plain php file and run it you will find the result you are looking for.

```
<?php
    $arr = array();
    $arr[] = array('taskname'=>'Coding','projname'=>'Easy Wedding');
    $arr[] = array('taskname'=>'Maintain','projname'=>'Easy Wedding');
    $arr[] = array('taskname'=>'Flow Chart','projname'=>'Fnn');
    $arr[] = array('taskname'=>'development in','projname'=>'Art gallery');
    echo json_encode(array('rows'=>$arr));
?>
```

It will create same json data as i created in javascript t variable.

Comment: how should i return json in correct format may be i am making mistake there so things are not working.. i want json to be returned as [
        {"taskname":"Coding","projname":"Easy Wedding"},
        {"taskname":"Maintain","projname":"Easy Wedding"},
        {"taskname":"Flow Chart","projname":"Fnn"},
        {"taskname":"development in ","projname":"Fnn"},
        {"taskname":"flow chart","projname":"Art gallery"}
    ]

Comment: @ianace it's json_encode(). for further information you can check http://php.net/manual/en/function.json-encode.php

Comment: @ianace i'm not encoding json. I'm encoding php array name $arr. json_encode() will create javascript equivalent object( in this case json). that you can get in your ajax success call and iterate it to get your result.

Answer (score 0):

Here is some code that may help:

#### From JSON to CI

1) CODEIGNITER

```
public function selectDetalleSolicitudByIdCliente() {
    $this->cliente_model->id_cliente = $_POST['id_cliente'];
    $data["cliente_detalle"] = $this->cliente_model->selectDetalleSolicitudByIdCliente();
    echo json_encode($data);
}
```

2) JQUERY

```
$.post(
    "cliente/selectDetalleSolicitudByIdCliente",
    {
        id_cliente: id_cliente
    },
    function(respuesta){
        $("#reporte2").html(">>" + respuesta);

        var respuesta = jQuery.parseJSON(respuesta);//parse json

        $.each(respuesta.cliente_detalle,function(index,value){
            for(var i in value){
                alert(i+' -> '+value[i]);
            }
     });
});
```